# compiling SFML with mingw has PTITLEBARINFO not declared

Tags: windows, cmake, mingw, sfml

When i try to compile the sfml-2.4.2 library with mingw i get the following error:

```
In file included from c:\mingw\include\windows.h:48:0,
                 from C:/Users/LENOVO/programming/SFML/SFML-2.4.1/src/SFML/Window/Win32/JoystickImpl.hpp:42,
                 from C:/Users/LENOVO/programming/SFML/SFML-2.4.1/src/SFML/Window/JoystickImpl.hpp:83,
                 from C:/Users/LENOVO/programming/SFML/SFML-2.4.1/src/SFML/Window/JoystickManager.hpp:32,
                 from C:\Users\LENOVO\programming\SFML\SFML-2.4.1\src\SFML\Window\Joystick.cpp:29:
c:\mingw\include\winuser.h:3920:47: error: 'PTITLEBARINFO' has not been declared
 WINUSERAPI BOOL WINAPI GetTitleBarInfo (HWND, PTITLEBARINFO);
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src\SFML\Window\CMakeFiles\sfml-window.dir\build.make:137: recipe for target 'src/SFML/Window/CMakeFiles/sfml-window.dir/Joystick.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [src/SFML/Window/CMakeFiles/sfml-window.dir/Joystick.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:227: recipe for target 'src/SFML/Window/CMakeFiles/sfml-window.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [src/SFML/Window/CMakeFiles/sfml-window.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:128: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I work on windows. I installed mingw via the MinGW Installation Manager. I used Cmake-3.9.3 to get the makefile etc. But when i run `mingw32-make` in the SFML-2.4.2 folder i get this error. I installed MinGW in C:\MinGW. (For that i used the newest mingw-get version 0.6.2-beta)

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the target version doesn't work.

This error happens (in my case) because of a broken include file:

```
 C:\MinGW\include\winuser.h
```

In this file, `PTITLEBARINFO` is declared at line 4417 
but it is referred in the declaration of `GetTitleBarInfo` at line 3920.

There is another `winuser.h` at

```
 C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\include\w32api\winuser.h
```

which seems to be correct.

Also, the `winuser.h` in `Visual-C++` which is located, for example, at

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\winuser.h
```

is correct.

So you need to fix the broken `winuser.h`, change your `include-path` or do something else.